# Merging two complete heaps

Tags: algorithms, trees, heaps

Suppose you have two heaps each containing $2^k - 1$ elements.

Design an efficient algorithm for merging these two heaps into a single heap.

My approach was to assume two heaps are maxheap. Create one node with value $-\infty$ and attach one heap as left subtree and another as right subtree, and call the heapify procedure. So it should take $O(\log(2(2^k-1)+1))=\log(k)$ time.

But my confusion is $-\infty$ valued node doesn't necessarily go at the last node of heap.

Comment: `last node of heap` you seem to be implying a specific implementation of _heap_ where there _is_ a `last node` - an "implied binary heap" in an array comes to mind. But: A heap is _not_ an ordered tree: the "least priority key" _does not need_ to end up in any given position - any leaf will do. Combining two  heaps implemented with links is trivial: select the highest priority key from both root nodes, remove it from its heap and create a new root node for the combined heap holding this key and having both "input heaps" as children. (Note that this doesn't necessarily keep "balance".)

Answer (score 1):

Calling heapify once isn't going to build a heap in one iteration  . Instead merge the two arrays which contain both heaps initially and call BuildHeap() procedure. You will get a heap in O(n) time.